# MassTransit Unit Testing and Faults

Tags: masstransit

I'm using MassTransit 8 and the AddMassTransitTestHarness method to wire up some testing. I have an IConsumer and in the Consume method I'm purposefully throwing a new exception just to test out the failure case and whether I can detect in the test that the message was NOT successfully consumed.

In the test I'm doing all of the following but they all pass successfully, which is unexpected:

```
Assert.That(await harness.Published.Any<MyMessage>(x => x.Context.Message.SiteId == siteId));
Assert.That(await harness.Consumed.Any<MyMessage>(x => x.Context.Message.SiteId == siteId));
var consumerHarness = harness.GetConsumerHarness<MyMessage>();
Assert.That(await consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<MyMessage>(x => x.Context.Message.SiteId == siteId));
Assert.False(await consumerHarness.Consumed.Any<Fault>());
Assert.False(await harness.Consumed.Any<Fault>());
```

My expectation is that the .Consumed.Any assertions would fail, because the message wasn't consumed successfully, or that the Assert.False on .Consumed.Any would fail (be true) because there was a fault.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To assert that a message was consumed *without* throwing an exception, you can specify the filter expression on the assertion:

```cs
Assert.That(await consumerHarness.Consumed
    .Any<MyMessage>(x => x.Context.Message.SiteId == siteId
                         && x.Exception is null));
```

Use the inverse to find messages that threw an exception.

```cs
Assert.That(await consumerHarness.Consumed
    .Any<MyMessage>(x => x.Context.Message.SiteId == siteId
                         && x.Exception != null));
```